# How to find records with multiple relations to a second table

Tags: mysql, database

```
table products
--------------
id | title
1  | Product 1
2  | Product 2
3  | Product 3

table categories
----------------
id | title
1  | Cat 1
2  | Cat 2
3  | Cat 3

table products_categories_mm
----------------
id_local | id_foriegn
1        | 2
1        | 3
2        | 3
3        | 2
```

```
SELECT * 
FROM products 
    JOIN products_categories_mm ON products.uid=products_categories_mm.uid_local 
    JOIN categories ON products_categories_mm.uid_foreign = categories.uid 
WHERE products.lang_uid IN (0) 
    AND products.page >= 1 
    AND products.page IN (8,9,10,11) 
    AND categories.uid IN (2,3) 
ORDER BY products.datetime DESC
```

The above finds all products related to categories 2 and 3. It returns product records 1, 2 and 3. This is fine and works as I want it to. But now I need to adjust the query so that it returns products that are related to both category 2 and category 3.

In this case, the query should then return product 1 (as it is the only product related to both categories).

I have tried changing my SQL to:

```
SELECT * 
FROM products 
    JOIN products_categories_mm ON products.uid=products_categories_mm.uid_local 
    JOIN categories ON products_categories_mm.uid_foreign = categories.uid 
WHERE products.lang_uid IN (0) 
    AND products.page >= 1 
    AND products.page IN (8,9,10,11) 
    AND (categories.uid = 2 AND categories.uid = 3)
ORDER BY products.datetime DESC
```

But this returns nothing. `EXPLAIN` says there is an impossible where clause.

How can I change my SQL to get the records I want?

Answer (score 1):

The SQL explanation is because the UID of 2 and 3 are going to appear in different rows so it is impossible to have a single row where the UID is both 2 and 3. It would probably be best to do a different approach... say for example a subquery.

Comment: can you give me an example? I have never had to use subqueries before

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    a.*
FROM
    products a
INNER JOIN
    products_categories_mm b ON a.uid = b.uid_local
WHERE
    a.lang_uid = 0
    AND a.page IN (8,9,10,11)
    AND b.uid_foreign IN (2,3)
GROUP BY
    a.uid
HAVING
    COUNT(*) = 2
ORDER BY
    a.datetime DESC
```

The `2` in `COUNT(*) = 2` represents the number of categories you want to check on. If you want the product to show up only if it satisfies 3 or 4 categories, change that number accordingly.

Comment: This does it! I just have to see how I can re-write my query using my CMS's API to create the above SQL.

Answer (score 1):

It is complaining because you have a simple logic failure in this line:

```
AND (categories.uid = 2 AND categories.uid = 3)
```

It can never be both of values, only one or the other. You must have meant:

```
AND (categories.uid = 2 OR categories.uid = 3)
```

Which could also be rewritten as:

```
AND (categories.uid IN (2,3))
```

---

As an aside, what is the point of:

```
AND products.page >= 1
```

if you're filtering it further down the line:

```
AND products.page IN (8,9,10,11)
```

You don't need the first bit of this.